# Graph Minimum Spanning Tree using BFS

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, breadth-first-search, minimum-spanning-tree

This is a problem from a practice exam that I'm struggling with:

> Let G = (V, E) be a weighted undirected connected graph, with positive
>   weights (you may assume that the weights are distinct). Given a real
>   number r, define the subgraph Gr = (V, {e in E | w(e) <= r}). For
>   example, G0 has no edges (obviously disconnected), and Ginfinity = G
>   (which by assumption is connected). The problem is to find the
>   smallest r such that Gr is connected.
>
> Describe an O(mlogn)-time algorithm that solves the problem by
>   repeated applications of BFS or DFS.

The real problem is doing it in O(mlogn). Here's what I've got:

```
r = min( w(e) )                            => O(m)
while true do                              => O(m) 
  Gr = G with edges e | w(e) > r removed     => O(m)
  if | BFS( Gr ).V | < |V|                   => O(m + n)
    r++ (or r = next smallest w(e))          
  else
    return r
```

That's a whopping O(m^2 + mn). Any ideas for getting it down to O(mlogn)? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are iterating over all possible edge costs which results in the outer loop of O(m). Notice that if the graph is disconnected when you discard all edges >w(e), it is also disconnected for >w(e') where `w(e') < w(e)`. You can use this property to do a binary search over the edge costs and thus do this in O(log(n)).

```
lo=min(w(e) for e in edges), hi=max(w(e) for e in edges)
while lo<hi:
   mid=(lo+hi)/2
   if connected(graph after discarding all e where w(e)>w(mid)):
       lo=mid
   else:
       hi=mid-1
return lo
```

The binary search has a complexity of O(log (max_e-min_e)) (you can actually bring it down to O(log(edges)) and discarding edges and determining connectivity can be done in O(edges+vertices), so this can be done in O((edge+vertices)*log(edges)).

Warning: I have not tested this in code yet, so there may be bugs. But the idea should work.

Comment: That is much better, but O( (m+n)logm ) is still > O(mlogn). There is also a big difference because logm > logn. Almost there!

Comment: Actually, O((m + n)log m) = O(m log n).  m + n = O(m), since n = O(m).  Also, since m = O(n^2), O(log m) = O(log (n^2)) = O(2 log n) = O(log n).  So O((m + n)log m) = O(m log n).

Answer (score 3):

How about the following algorithm?

First take a list of all edges (or all distinct edge lengths, using ) from the graph and sort them. That takes O(m*log m) = O(m*log n) time: m is usually less than n^2, so O(log m)=O(log n^2)=O(2*log n)=O(log n).

It is obvious that r should be equal to the weight of some edge. So you can do a binary search on the index of the edge in the sorted array.

For each index you try, you take the length of the correspondong edge as r, and check the graph for connectivity, only using the edges of length <= r with BFS or DFS.

Each iteration of the binary search takes O(m), and you have to make O(log m)=O(log n) iterations.

Comment: I don't think we can assume that m < n^2, so this is O( mlogm + (m+n)logm ) = O( (m+n)logm ).

Comment: @Garrett- You can assume that m <= n^2 since for any pair of edges there is at most one edge between that pair.